# How do you write the conditions for the middle number when sorting 3 numbers in ascending order using if-else statements in java?

Tags: java

I've been trying different conditions but I can't seem to get it right. When I type 54, 53, 57, the output is correct. But when I type the same numbers in a different order, the output becomes 53, 0 , 57. Help please

This is my code for the middle number. I can't find out what's wrong.

```
if (num1<num2 && num1>num3){ //for middle number
secNum = num1;

}else if (num2<num1 && num2>num3){
secNum = num2;
   
}else if (num3<num1 && num3>num2){
secNum = num3;  
}
```

Comment: Please add the code which you have written

Comment: I just edited my post, forgot to post my code. I'm just a beginner, very sorry if  my code looks off

Comment: You assign `num2`  to `secNum` if `num3 < num2 < num1` but no in the case of `num1 < num2 < num3`. You'd probably need two expressions (joined with `||`) for that

Comment: You have literally hardcoded 3 out of 6 cases. In my opinion, hard coding is perfectly fine as long as you only deal with 3 numbers, but certainly prone to erroneous code & bad practice. ALSO, you have to write the rest of the 3 cases to fit the rest of the cases.

Comment: How is addressing half the possible cases "perfectly fine", unless you don't mind getting the wrong answer half of the time?

Comment: I was referring to the hardcoding! My bad. @KevinAnderson

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if you're familiar with arrays

```
import java.util.*; 
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = s.nextInt();
        int num2  = s.nextInt();
        int num3 =   s.nextInt();
        int arr[] = {num1,num2,num3};
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        System.out.println(arr[1]);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but our professor requires us to use the if-else statement

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 numbers, which can be in 6 different orders:

- num1, num2, num3
- num1, num3, num2
- num2, num1, num3
- num2, num3, num1
- num3, num1, num2
- num3, num2, num1

But your code has only 3 if-cases, which check for 3 possible orders.
That is why 3 out of 6 cases are wrong.
(If numbers can have the same value, you need to check with <= or >=)

So to keep you algorithm style, it has to be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    int num1 = 59;
    int num2 = 57;
    int num3 = 55;
    int secNum = 0;
    if (num1 < num2 && num1 < num3) {
        if (num2 < num3)
            secNum = num2;
        else
            secNum = num3;
    } else if (num2 < num1 && num2 < num3) {
        if (num1 < num3)
            secNum = num1;
        else
            secNum = num3;
    } else if (num3 < num1 && num3 < num2) {
        if (num1 < num2)
            secNum = num1;
        else
            secNum = num2;
    }
    System.out.println(secNum);
}
```

But Java has a lot of better ways to sort numbers, so I can not recommend this approach.

Comment: There are errors on the second if-else statement. It won't run

Comment: I added the main method and printing the result at the end - but there was no error in the 2nd if-statement. Maybe copy & paste broke something.

Comment: I'll try it again, but I didn't copy paste the one a while ago. Thank you for being patient

Comment: I just realized that your code is just meant to print out the second number with the 3 numbers already in the code. We are required to use Scanner, what changes can I make?

Comment: You can just replace your if-else logic in your question / scanner code with mine. So you remove the main-method, the variable definition and the System.out.

Answer (score 0):

This Will Work

```
   import java.util.*; 
    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            int num1 = s.nextInt();
            int num2  = s.nextInt();
            int num3 =   s.nextInt();
            int secNum=0;
            if(num2>num1 && num1>num3 || num3>num1 && num1>num2){
              secNum=num1;
            }
            if(num1>num2 && num2>num3 || num3>num2 && num2>num1){
              secNum=num2;
            }
            if(num1>num3 && num3>num2 || num2>num3 && num3>num1){
              secNum=num3;
            }
        System.out.print(secNum);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. However, we need all three inputted numbers in the output. Should I simply add firstNum and thirdNum?

Comment: if you need these to be in order maybe you should find min or max between the two and then print in order

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = s.nextInt();
        int num2  = s.nextInt();
        int num3 =   s.nextInt();

        int secNum = 0;
        if (num1 < num2 && num1 < num3) {
            secNum = Math.min(num2, num3);
        } else if (num2 < num1 && num2 < num3) {
            secNum = Math.min(num1, num3);
        } else if (num3 < num1 && num3 < num2) {
            secNum = Math.min(num1, num2);
        }
        System.out.println(secNum);
    }

}
```

Comment: Our output requires us to show all three sorted numbers. What changes can I make to the code so that all 3 appear? Will it be enough if I just add firstNum and thirdnum?

Comment: I've done it already and it worked. Thank you so much!